# Config enable sharding collection in MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, clustering, nosql, sharding, distributed-databases

I'm a new in MongoDB cluster.   I have a question about config enable shading collection in MongoDB:
I have a cluster :
**Shard1: replical01/node1:27017, node2:27017

Shard2: replical02/node3:27017, node4:27017**
2 config Server on other virtual machine.
Everything worked normally under manual. But I have a question as follows: how can I just shading a collection for only one shard. For example, I used mongos to create a database **Test**  with 3 collection **T1**, **T2**, **T3**.
Which **T1** only located on **shard1**, **T2** only on **shard2**. **T3** is also located on the both **shard1** and **shard2**.
Please help me. Thank you and regards!!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable sharding on collection base, i.e. collection T3 is sharded.

Unsharded collection are created in the **Primary Shard**, see [Sharded and Non-Sharded Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/index.html#sharded-and-non-sharded-collections)

> **Sharded and Non-Sharded Collections**
>
> A database can have a mixture of sharded and unsharded collections. Sharded collections are partitioned and distributed across the shards in the cluster. Unsharded collections are stored on a primary shard. Each database has its own primary shard.

Typically the Primary Shard is the least loaded shard at the time when the database was created. When you are not happy with the selected Primary Shard then you can move it with [movePrimary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/) command. But you have to move all collections of one database, you cannot move a single collection.

```
db.adminCommand( { movePrimary: <databaseName>, to: <newPrimaryShard> } )
```